# Enterprise Architect - how to extract nullability of a database table column?

Tags: database, nullable, enterprise-architect, non-nullable

I have a database table defined in EA. In this table I have a column where NULL is allowed. When I use a script or an API to extract nullability from this column, I understand this should be done using the LowerBound and UpperBound values. When `LowerBound` is 0, it is a nullable field, if it is 1, NULL is not allowed.

[image]

However, when I set the NULL field, LowerBound is still 1, as noted on the following picture:

[image]

How can I correctly extract nullability from a database column?

Comment: Where from did you get that wisdom that `lowerbound == 0` means nullable??

Answer (score 0):

You have to look into `Attribute.AllowDuplicates` or `t_attribute.AllowDuplicates` (well, it's EA).

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be two ways of retrieving that information:

1. Via SQL
2. Via API

Extending your example I defined to additional columns: `NotNullAttribute` and `NullAttribute` as shown in the figure below:

[image: Database table and its columns]

Now you get the results shown below when querying the element and its attributes:

LINQ and SQL query showing nullable columns:

[image: <code>AllowDuplicates</code> attribute reflects the <code>NotNull</code> setting or a database table's column]

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
  [t_attribute] [t]
WHERE
  [t].[Name] LIKE '%NullAttribute%'
```

Script for showing database table columns attributes:

```js
function main(id)
{
    var element AS EA.Element;
    element = Repository.GetElementByID(id);

    var attributes AS EA.Collection;
    attributes = element.Attributes;
    for(var c = 0; c < attributes.Count; c++)
    {
        var attribute AS EA.Attribute;
        attribute = attributes.GetAt(c);

        Session.Output(attribute.Name + ": " + attribute.AllowDuplicates);
    }
}

main(18365);

// Output
/*
Id: true    
Name: false 
CustomerTypeEnumId: true    
NotNullAttribute: true  
NullAttribute: false    
*/
```